Can we take CSS variable value in CSS @keyframes animation?

[EDIT]: To moderators, please read the question carefully before being
in hurry to mark the question duplicate. This question more to take
CSS variable value from JS (set in element style) and not to update in
@keyframe. There is code snippet attached (which includes JS part too.

I'm working on building an analog clock using CSS animations, and I've managed to get most of it done. However, to position the clock's hands (hour, minute, and second) according to the current time, I need to use JavaScript to set a variable in the CSS element. I want the animation to begin from this starting point. Is this possible?
Here’s my working code: https://jsfiddle.net/ashishanexpert/yjk78t0f/,
and this is where I want the CSS variables to be applied:


@keyframes move-niddle {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(calc(0 + var(--start)) deg);
  }

  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}




The linked question is about animating variables' value, this one is about using variables' value in animation

you can add deg in the variable (--start: 30deg;) and use it like this: transform: rotate(var(--start));. If you want to keep the variable numeric for other use, you need to "cast" it to angle value by multiplication: transform: rotate(calc(var(--start)) * 1deg);
